# How does MMU deal with Memory mapped registers?

Tags: virtual-memory, mmu

Am I correct when I say that addresses of memory mapped registers are always physical addresses?

If yes then how does MMU deal with these addresses and decide not to do virtual to physical translations for them?

Answer (score 3):

The MMU doesn't decide anything.  It merely maps addresses according to what it has been told by the OS: virtual addresses to physical ones, and/or interrupts the application program if the mapping for a particular physical address is marked as "invalid" or somehow inconsistent with the operation of the current machine instruction (e.g., for instruction fetches, "not executable", for stores, "read only", etc.).

The operating system establishes a set of rules and conventions that ensure that applications cannot create greif for one another.   If writing to memory-mapped I/O devices is OK for this OS, then the OS will set MMU mappings (e.g. page map registers) to allow it; otherwise it will not set MMU pages to map to I/O devices.

For most general purpose OSes, allowing arbitrary programs to write to I/O registers is a definition of "causes grief" and they simply never set up such a mapping.  This is how Windows acts from the point of user processes.

For special purpose OSes, have separate processes share I/O pages may be fine, especially if the processes running are trusted (e.g, part of the OS or pass some certification authority who asserts good quality).  Then multiple trusted processes might share memory-mapped I/O devices safely and conveniently.  Even untrusted processes can be run on such an OS; it simply doesn't give them access to I/O.

Back in 1972, I built a unique virtual memory 16 bit minicomputer.  The MMU had two kinds of page mappings:  mapping of virtual pages to physical (as you'd expect), and mapping of a page to a *single* 32 byte I/O device.  What this means is that the OS can hand *any* process any device (not critical to OS function) safely.

In particular, it meant that each I/O driver has its own address space; if it screwed up, no problem.  You could debug device drivers while running the OS without fear. (Windows suffered from I/O driver corruption destroying windows for years; still does I think but their quality control "trustedness checking" is wicked strong now).

Alas, it wasn't a commercial success.  I was forced to go into software to make a living :-{

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

All registers and or memory locations within a processor's memory map *are* physical addresses.

Virtual to physical translations are done by the MMU and only occur within contiguous blocks of memory in which code can be executed from. i.e RAM or internal flash. No virtual to physical translations occur when other parts of the memory map are accessed, because they do not interact with the MMU.

Comment: I think I am still missing something. When I do a simple LOAD/STORE to some, say 32 bit, address then how does my CPU know if this is memory mapped address and it needs no translation and therefore not involve MMU? Virtual addresses can span 0-2^32 address space right?

Comment: On standard virtual architectures, all addresses issued by your program running in its virtual space, are mapped by the MMU.  You don't get to choose. (There may be architectures in which part of the space is not handled by the MMU, but they would be considered unusual).

Comment: Correct again. Program address `0x0000` may be mapped to virtual address `0xF45DAC34` which may be physically located at `0x2020FC43`. The MMU handles the translation between each of these values as required, if it has been configured to do so.